An elementary inequality problem with 6 variables
I am trying to prove/disprove the following statement.

Given $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ and $0\leq a,b,c <1$ such that $x+y+z =0$ and $a^2x+ b^2y+c^2z<0$. Then $ax+by+cz<0$.

In my context, $[x,y,z]^\top$ represents the entrywise product of two vectors $u,v \in\mathbb{R}^K$, $K=3$, which come from an orthonormal basis, so one may assume that $x,y,z \in [0,1]$. On the other hand $[a,b,c]$ are the diagonal elements of a diagonal matrix $D$ with $0\leq a,b,c<1$ (but only 1 of them is/might be 0). The statement becomes "If $u^\top D^2 v<0 $ then $u^\top D v<0$". The above statement can be seen as an elementary version for $K=3$, but it would be great if one can prove/disprove it for general $K$.
For $K=2$ (i.e. $z=0$) it is quite easy to prove using $y=-x$ and we even don't need the condition$a,b<1$.

Take $x=3,y=-1,z=-2$.
The mentioned 'result' would imply that, if $3a^2-b^2-2c^2<0$, then $3a-b-2c<0$.
But this is false, as taking for instance $a=1/4,b=1/2,c=1/10$ we have $$3a^2-b^2-2c^2=-\dfrac{41}{80}<0\quad 3a-b-2c=\dfrac{1}{20}>0$$
This of course implies the result is false for $K\geq 3$, as we may take all other 'coordinates' $0$, and $a,b,c,x,y,z$ as above.
